# Dropbox - Nemo integration under Fedora

Tags: fedora, cinnamon, nemo

I want to add a right-click copy Dropbox link under: Fedora 25, Cinnamon 3.2.x, Nemo 3.2.x

- The `nemo-dropbox` doesn't work under Fedora.

  Info:

  - https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/nemo-dropbox
  - https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/tree/master/nemo-dropbox
- The command `dropbox sharelink ~/Dropbox/filename | tr -d '\n' | xsel -ib` works perfect and copy the URL to the clipboard.

  Info:

  - https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/9192
  - https://superuser.com/questions/837307/how-to-get-the-url-of-dropbox-file-from-command-line
  - [How to install Dropbox (and have Dropbox file manager integration) without Nautilus?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170540/how-to-install-dropbox-and-have-dropbox-file-manager-integration-without-nauti)
  - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/anyone-had-success-using-dropbox-with-nemo-4175460507/
- Try to add it on a Nemo action at `~/.local/share/nemo/actions/dropbox.nemo_action`:

  ```
  [Nemo Action]
  Active=true
  Name=Share with Dropbox
  Comment=Share %F with Dropbox
  Exec=dropbox sharelink %F | tr -d '\n' | xsel -ib
  Icon-Name=dropbox
  Selection=s
  Extensions=any;
  Dependencies=xsel;
  Quote=double
  ```

  with no luck... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Was easier than I thought... I have to run the command in a shell...

```
Exec=sh -c 'dropbox sharelink %F | xsel -ib'
```